# Flutter AnimatedList data set change form network

Tags: flutter, animation

```dart
Future updateHistory() async {
    final value = await fetchHistory();
    setState(() {
      history = value;
    });
  }
```

How to calculate whats change in dataset for AnimatedList
to use in
`_listKey.currentState!.insertItem(index)`
and
`_listKey.currentState!.removeItem(index, (context, animation) => MyItem(history[index], animation)`